# PHP hexadecimal matrix map

Tags: php, bin2hex

I have hexadecimal content saved inside a string, however I would like to get a value that is located at a specific address (ex. 0xD3)

I have the following code to read the .bin file and show it's content:

```
$handle = @fopen($file, "r");
        if ($handle) {
            while (!feof($handle)) {

                $hex = bin2hex(fread ($handle , 16 ));
                print $hex."\n";

                $input_output .= $hex;

            }

            fclose($handle);

        }
```

I am looking for a way to map the addresses in order to find the values I want to.
Ideas ? thanks in advance

Comment: If you convert the address of the byte you want to decimal, use `fseek()` to position in the file and read the data.

Comment: thanks but fseek returns 0 on success or -1 on failure, I need the value data

Comment: `fseek()` just positions the file pointer - then `fread()` the data.